# Why cannot use "console.WriteLine" in winUI3 app (C++)? error: 'Console': is not a class or namespace

Tags: debugging, console, winui-3

I recently write a simple test app(which is a winUI3 app (C++)), and I want to put some message to console, in order to help me with debugging.
I used "console.WriteLine" but get this error: 'Console': is not a class or namespace.
I looked up in the Microsoft website, but it couldn't work either.(I could not include "system" in my .cpp file)

the code is following:

```
using namespace system; // would get this Error:'system': a namespace with this name does not exist

using namespace winrt::Windows::UI::Popups;
using namespace std;
using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;

using namespace Microsoft::UI::Xaml;
namespace winrt::SampleApp::implementation


{ 
  LoginPage::LoginPage()

{
   InitializeComponent();
   Console::WriteLine("hello!");
}
```

I have looked up following links, but got no luck.
[this is for c#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/281681/vs-2019-consolewriteline-output-not-present-in-out.html)

I just want a way to show the messages to help me debug.

Console is a good way, and I also tried OutputDebugString but no message output in the output window. Where did I do wrongly?

Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot! Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why cannot use "console.WriteLine" in winUI3 app (C++)?

Because `System.Console` is a .NET API.

If you want to print something to the debug output window in a WinUI 3 C++ app you could use the `OutputDebugStringA` function:

```
LoginPage::LoginPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    OutputDebugStringA("hello1!\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but how can I see the output? from "show output from"? how shall I set it?

Comment: There is only four items found: build, build order, deployment, package manager. How can I find "debug" or set it up?

Comment: Run your app with the debugger attached (Debug->Start Debugging or press F5).

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried 'cout << "Value of a is " << a;'

Comment: For short descriptions, please add Comments, instead of Answers.

Comment: Before you comment on my answer, i suggest you check my profile and count my reputation points.